# Couldn't run android unit test cases with Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

My Gradle Configuration:

```
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.4.0'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.0RC2'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.7.0RC2'
```

With these Gradle setting, when I try to run the unit test cases, I am getting below error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/exceptions/Reporter
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor5.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) 
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:45) 
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.newInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:260) 
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.newInstance(Whitebox.java:139) 
    at org.powermock.api.extension.reporter.AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.getInstanceForClassLoader(AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.java:41) 
    at org.powermock.api.extension.reporter.AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.create(AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.java:35) 
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.getMockingFrameworkReporter(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:140) 
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:119) 
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53) 
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59) 
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) 
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) 
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) 
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) 
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) 
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) 
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) 
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) 
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) 
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117) 
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42) 
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262) 
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) 
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.exceptions.Reporter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) 
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) 
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:190) 
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:77) 
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ... 29 more`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the powermock 2 instead.

`org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0RC2`

[Please Refer the Github issue](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/726#issuecomment-294135057)